# Solidity ParserError: Expected identifier but got '(' constuctor() public { ^

Tags: constructor, blockchain, solidity, identifier, smartcontracts

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract MyContract {
// Mappings
mapping(uint => string) public names;

constuctor() public {
    names[1] = "Adam";
    names[2] = "Bruce";
    names[3] = "Carl";
}
```

}

I tried compiling this code on remix.ethereum.org and I got the following error:

Solidity ParserError: Expected identifier but got '(' constuctor() public { ^

How can I go about solving this issue? Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your constructor declaration :

```
constructor() public {
```

instead of

```
constuctor() public {
```

"r" is missing